# Disabling HTML views cache when a user is logged in

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

I am trying to get the views cache disabled in CakePHP when I one of my users logs in.  I have found that if I disable the cache.check in the core, it stops searching the cache/views folder for the cached view and leaves the existing cache file in place. I want to be able to dynamically turn off cache.check when my users log in. I do not want to delete the cache files, only disable them for logged in users.

I have tried a wide range of solutions, but have failed at every attempt. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly!

Comment: @ndm Noted, I will do so in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CacheDispatcher` filter is responsible for [**dispatching cached views**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.1/lib/Cake/Routing/Filter/CacheDispatcher.php#L40), so you have to hook into this process somewhere, and based on whether a user is currently logged in, change the value of `Cache.check` before the dispatcher filter does its work.

You could for example do that in your bootstrap

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

if(AuthComponent::user()) {
    Configure::write('Cache.check', false);
}
```

Alternatively, and for better testability, you could move that into a custom dispatcher filter that is run before or instead of the original cache dispatcher

**app/Routing/Filter/MyCustomCacheDispatcher.php**

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
App::uses('CakeEvent', 'Event');
App::uses('CacheDispatcher', 'Routing/Filter');

class MyCustomCacheDispatcher extends CacheDispatcher
{
    public function beforeDispatch(CakeEvent $event)
    {
        if(AuthComponent::user()) {
            Configure::write('Cache.check', false);
        }
        parent::beforeDispatch($event);
    }
}
```

**bootstrap**

```
Configure::write('Dispatcher.filters', array(
    'AssetDispatcher',
    'MyCustomCacheDispatcher'
    //'CacheDispatcher'
));
```

In case your are using a custom session key, make sure that `AuthComponent::$sessionKey` is set to the expected value *before* these checks are done!

See also

- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html**

Comment: Thank you for this well thought out answer, It has been very helpful and insightful into how cakePHP works.

Comment: The only thing I found is when I change the debug value for 0 to 2, it sends an Fatal Error:
Error: Class 'AuthComponent' not found 
File: /var/www/site/app/Config/bootstrap.php 
Line: 99       I found I can clear this by removing the AuthComponets from the bootstrap, and readding them after one refresh.

Comment: But I found it shows up after every instance of the server restarting.

Comment: Ah, I found the solution, in bootstrap, I am now using App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component'); instead.

Comment: @KevinWeber Sorry, my bad, just woke up when I wrote this :) I'll update my answer.